# How to match dimensions in CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to build a CNN, where the goal is from 3 features to predict the label, but is giving an error of dimension.
Could someone help me?
updated after comments from @M.Innat

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, mean_absolute_error
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn import metrics
import tensorflow as tf
import random 

# Create data
n = 8500
l = [2, 3, 4, 5,6]
k = int(np.ceil(n/len(l)))
labels = [item for item in l for i in range(k)]
random.shuffle(labels,random.random)
labels =np.array(labels)
label_unique = np.unique(labels)


x = np.linspace(613000, 615000, num=n) + np.random.uniform(-5, 5, size=n)
y = np.linspace(7763800, 7765800, num=n) + np.random.uniform(-5, 5, size=n)
z = np.linspace(1230, 1260, num=n) + np.random.uniform(-5, 5, size=n)

X = np.column_stack((x,y,z))
Y = labels
# Split the dataset into training and testing.
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1234)
seq_len=len(X_train)
n_features=len(X_train[0])
droprate=0.1
exit_un=len(label_unique)
seq_len=len(X_train)
n_features=len(X_train[0])
droprate=0.1
exit_un=len(label_unique)
print('n_features: {} \n seq_len: {} \n exit_un: {}'.format(n_features,seq_len,exit_un))
X_train = X_train[..., None][None, ...] # add channel axis+batch aix
Y_train = pd.get_dummies(Y_train) # transform to one-hot encoded 

drop_prob = 0.5
my_model = Sequential()
my_model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(seq_len,n_features,1),filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same',activation="relu"))        # 1 channel of grayscale.
my_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,1)))
my_model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(5,5), padding='same',activation="relu"))
my_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,1)))
my_model.add(Flatten())
my_model.add(Dense(units = 1024, activation="relu"))
my_model.add(Dropout(rate=drop_prob))
my_model.add(Dense(units = exit_un, activation="softmax"))

n_epochs = 100
batch_size = 10 
learn_rate = 0.005

# Define the optimizer and then compile.
my_optimizer=Adam(lr=learn_rate)
my_model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = my_optimizer, metrics=['categorical_crossentropy','accuracy'])

my_summary = my_model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=n_epochs, batch_size = batch_size, verbose = 1)
```

The error I have is:

> ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
> x sizes: 1
> y sizes: 5950
> Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the input sample without the channel axis and also the batch axis. Also, according to your loss function, you should transform your integer label to one-hot encoded.

```
exit_un=len(label_unique)
drop_prob = 0.5

X_train = X_train[..., None][None, ...] # add channel axis+batch aix
X_train = np.repeat(X_train, repeats=100, axis=0) # batch-ing
Y_train = np.repeat(Y_train, repeats=100, axis=0) # batch-ing
Y_train = pd.get_dummies(Y_train) # transform to one-hot encoded 
print(X_train.shape, Y_train.shape)

my_model = Sequential()
...
```

### update

Based on the discussion, it seems like you need the `conv1d` operation in the modeling time and need to reshape your sample as mentioned in the comment. Here is the [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16VcT5MkP_rhXcRW3PKCG-ejNY6kZRF3E?usp=sharing), it should work now.

Comment: Thank you, @M.Innat, it works, but I don't understand well, I was working  with image before, and the shape used to be the number of images x width x height x rgb, here I thought that would be the size of the table x 1. Do you know any book /blog which explains that? When you put 'repeats=100' is because the size of the data or the number of epochs ?

Comment: In an RGB image, the shape is always (h, w, 3). Now, when we train the vision model, we normally pass a number of images, and the shape of `X_train` becomes: `(100, h, w, 3)` where 100 is the number of images and here it's also referring to the batch axis.

Comment: In your example, after splitting the shape of `X_train` was `(h, w)`. So, I added a channel axis (by `[..., None]`) and next add batch axis (by `[None, ...]`). By now the shape of `X_train` would be ([`1, h, w, 1`]). And lastly, we want a few more samples to train, and so for demonstration purposes, I repeated this same sample (`X_train`) multiple times (here 100) with `repeats=100)`. And lastly, it gave us ([`100, h, w, 1`]). Here, 100 is the batch size or the number of samples. PS, in your actual data, you should not use this repeat function, rather use `reshape` maybe.

Comment: So, let's suppose that my real data are 1000x7 matrix, in this case, for training I would have [1, 1000, 7, 1] , I must reshape that in order for the first axis to be = 100, like np.reshape(X_train, (100,10,7,1)) ?

Comment: Only works if I create the fictitious data with 'repeats=100', If I keep my real data doesn't work, it gives the error :  x = 1 and  y = 5950, because now my X_train = [1,5950, 3,1] and my Y_train = [5950, 5]

Comment: It depends on the modeling approach. If I model to take shape as `(7, 1)`, then for input matrix (`X.shape == (1000, 7)`), I would do `np.reshape(a, (-1, 7, 1))`. ( Ps, You should not use np. repeat for your actual data. It repeats the same samples. ) If there's no issue with NDA, it'd be better to share a small set of actual data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241065/discussion-between-jeniffer-barreto-and-m-innat).

Comment: I updated the answer.